# Laravel is my simple stateless auth filter ok to use

Tags: php, mysql, api, authentication, laravel

I made a simple stateless auth filter in Laravel in order to auth users using my restAPI.

It works by sending http headers (simple demo) eg:

**curl -u "5454:5454_23423dsfsdfDDdsf"**

The first parameter is the users ID the second one is a the api_key.

The server then checks the user by the id that was sent, then check if the api_key that was sent matches the on in the DB.

I could also do a "WHERE api_key = key" but it seems slow to do a where statement in the mysql DB on a archer field. So instead I do a lookup by the ID then check if the api key matches.

So is this filter OK?

```
Route::filter('api.auth', function()
{
    if (!Request::getUser())
    {
        App::abort(401, 'A valid user ID and API key is required');
    }

    $user = User::where('user_id', '=', Request::getUser())->first(['api_key']);

    if (!$user)
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }

    if ($user->api_key == Request::getPassword())
    {
        Auth::login($user);
    }
    else
    {
        App::abort(401);
    }
});
```